# Unknown format in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4. But I am getting unknown format error. Do you guys have any help for me.
Here is my controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Entry.all
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: But its working perfectly on rails 3 only problem in rails 4

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add this to your routes config

`resources :entries, defaults: { format: 'json' }`

Comment: @user3366155 glad it helped. would you mind choosing my answer :)

Comment: Thanks mate, was looking for this for ages!

Answer (score 9):

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|

    @entry = Entry.all

    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @entry }

  end
end
```

hope it will help you

Comment: :) while this may not have concerned OP, this was what I was looking for! (I wanted to return the regular html view as default, but respond to `.json` in a different way

Comment: This is very helpful! It just works! However I don't understand why does it work?

Answer (score -2):

Add `:html` to `respond_to` (`respond_to :html, :json`) or remove the `respond_to` call altogether.

Comment: in Rails 4.2.2, adding `respond_to` at Controller-level gives an error about how it has been moved to a `gem`