# Unable to restrict redirection of page on File Upload in rails 5.0.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am uploading a file in my chat application, but on upload it is redirecting the page. I have tried in many ways to restrict it but i failed.

Please help me with your valuable response.

**Attachment Model:**

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :chat

    validates_presence_of :user_id , :chat_id

    has_attached_file :attachment
    validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /.*/
end
```

**Attachment Controller:**

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user
    layout false

    def create
        @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
        @attachment = @chat.attachments.build(attachment_params)
        @attachment.user_id = current_user.id
        if @attachment.save
            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
                message: @attachment.attachment,
                user: @attachment.user.name,
                action: "attachment"            
            head :ok 
        end     
    end

    private
        def attachment_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:attachment)
        end
end
```

**Attachment View:**

```
<%= form_for @attachment  , url: "/chats/#{@chat.id}/attachments", :remote => true,  authenticity_token: true, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :chat_id, value: @chat.id %>

    <input type="file" name="post[attachment]" onchange="this.form.submit();return false;" id="message_attachment" type="file">

<% end %>
```

**Javascript for updating on Front-end:(using Rails ActionCable)**

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel',{
    received: function(data) {
        $('#new-messages').removeClass('hidden');
        if (data.action == "attachment") {
            return $('#new-messages').append(this.renderAttachment(data));  
        }
    },
    renderAttachment: function(data) {
        return data.message //"<li class='<%= self_or_other(data)%>'><div class='chatboxmessagecontent'><p>" + data.message + "</p>" + data.user + " • " + "</div></li>";       
    }
})
```

***EDIT - 1***

**In Front End I am updating as**

```
<% if @attachments.any? %>              
    <div id="messages">
        <%= render partial: 'attachments/attachment', collection: @attachments %>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" id="new-messages"></div>
    <span id="istyping"></span>         
<% else %>
    <div class="hidden" id="new-messages"></div>
<% end %>
```

**Attachment Parital**

```
<li class="<%=  self_or_other(attachment) %>">
  <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">

    <a href="<%= attachment.attachment.url %>"  download>
        <%= image_tag attachment.attachment.url, height: '64', width: '64' %>
    </a><br/>

    <time datetime="<%= attachment.created_at %>" title="<%= attachment
    .created_at.strftime("%d %b  %Y at %I:%M%p") %>">
      <%= message_interlocutor(attachment).name %> • <%= attachment.created_at.strftime("%H:%M %p") %>
    </time>

  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On removing of ***`head: ok`*** in Controller File. It is not redirecting.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason you are getting redirected is because you are not specifying how to respond to different request formats. I would need to see your server log for somethings along the lines of:

```
Started GET "/chats/#{@chat.id}/attachments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-13 15:38:23 +0900

Processing by Rails::AttachmentsController#create as HTML #<= this
```

You must specify how to respond to different request formats such as `HTML` or `JS`. Your form is using the `remote: true` param so it should be a `JS` request(`ajax`).

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
      @attachment = @chat.attachments.build(attachment_params)
      @attachment.user_id = current_user.id
      if @attachment.save
        broadcast_attachment(@attachment)
        return head :no_content
      end
    end
  end
end

def broadcast_attachment(attachment)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages', message: attachment.attachment,
                                           user: attachment.user.name,
                                           action: 'attachment'
end
```

Let me know if the problem persists.

EDIT#1

When using the `respond_to` method, you must also specify the `HTML` format for some reason.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    ...
  end
  format.html { ... }
end
```

If you just need the default behavior for `HTML`, you can simply use:

`format.html`

Comment: I used this, but it will give '**ActionController::UnknownFormat**' . I updating the attachment at Front-end as i mentioned in the Q.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry! You must also specify the html format, please see my edit

Comment: Also, according to this SO answer: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590408/unknown-format-in-rails-4`, it seems possible to specify the default format for a route in the `config/routes.rb`

Comment: it is not saving the attachment. Please check my edit i have updated view code.

Comment: there was a problem with my method. I put back your code as it was.

Comment: It is responding  as HTML.


Started POST "/chats/16/attachments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-13 15:19:26 +0530
Processing by AttachmentsController#create as HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123232/discussion-between-modi-ranga-nayakulu-and-shiyason).